# optimal stretegy

Tags: probability-theory

Imagine the following game. A player rolls a die. If the player rolls a $6$ the player wins no money. Otherwise, the player
may either quit the game and win $k$ dollars, where $k$ is the roll of the die, or may roll again. If the player  rolls
again, the game continues until either a $6$ is rolled or the player quits. The total payoff for the game is always $k$ dollars, where
$k$ is the value of the last roll (unless the roll is a $6$ in which case the payoff is zero). What is the optimal strategy
for the player?

Comment: The only plausible strategies are (1) accept first roll, (2) reject roll of 1, (3) reject rolls of 1,2, (4) reject rolls of 1,2,3 and (5) reject rolls of 1,2,3,4. It is easy to calculate that these give expected outcomes of 5/2,14/5,3,3,5/4. So you should reject a roll of 1 and accept a roll of 4 or 5.

Comment: You need to define "optimal" - what is the "objective function", that is, what is the player trying to maximize? You can't say "the amount he receives" because that is not a deterministic number, it is a random variable. You can't maximize a random variable; you can maximize the expected value of a r. v. or you can, for example, maximize the expected value minus one half the variance. Some risk-averse players will accept a guaranteed payoff of 2 dollars (after they roll the die) over an uncertain payoff with an expected value of 2.25 dollars.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that the player maximises the expected payoff.

Rolling less than or equal to the current roll doesn't improve the payoff, so the player shouldn't reroll unless the expected change in the payoff in case of a higher number is positive.

Clearly the player should quit with a $5$, since no improvement is possible.

With a $4$, the expected change in the payoff in case of a higher number is $\frac12\cdot1-\frac12\cdot4\lt0$, so the player should quit with a $4$.

With a $3$, the expected change in the payoff in case of a higher number is $\frac13\cdot1+\frac13\cdot2-\frac13\cdot3=0$, so the player should quit with a $3$.

If the player should reroll with a $2$, she should also reroll with a $1$, so the expected payoff upon rerolling a $2$ satisfies $x=\frac16(x+x+3+4+5+0)$, with solution $x=3\gt2$, so the player should reroll with a $1$ or $2$, and the expected payoff of the game is $3$. (Thus the player is in fact indifferent whether to reroll a $3$.)